# pandas compare dataframes and write/read result to/from excel - how to get the compare format back into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

How can I read the pandas.dataframe.compare result back from excel into an equivalent dataframe?

If I do

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 4],  # Changed here, '3' to '4'
    'B': [4, 5, 6]
})

df1.compare(df2,keep_equal=True,keep_shape=True)
```

I get a nice comparison and can write it to excel:

[image]

But how can I read this excel into a dataframe and get the same layout? `dfd = pd.read_excel(tmp_file,header=[0,1])` does not work (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you also need to pass `index_col=0`:

```
(df1.compare(df2,keep_equal=True,keep_shape=True)
    .to_excel('out.xlsx')
)

pd.read_excel('out.xlsx', index_col=0, header=[0, 1])
```

Output:

```
     A          B      
  self other self other
0    1     1    4     4
1    2     2    5     5
2    3     4    6     6
```

Comment: great, works; thanks!